# Javascript validation for text area

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a text area which should only accept values like this format on on change validation:
`string1-value1`,  `string2-value2`, `string3-value3`,... For example India - IND, USA - US, Kenya - Kya. How can I do it using javascript validation. I tried some validations, but not working. Please help me.

Comment: can you show a demo what you tried.

Comment: See [JavaScript Form Validation and Regular Expression Basics](http://www.anthoniraj.com/javascript-form-validation-and-regular-expression-basics/)

Comment: Are the value determined from a list or an array?

Comment: @zipp There is no difference in JavaScript…?

Comment: @Zip It will be string manually entered and onchange it will check whether in correct format or not

Comment: i think <textarea><div id ="div_id"  onkeypress=" function()" ></div></textarea> inside div you have to validate

Comment: @royhowie not as far as I know, I just wanted to make sure if it was predetermined or not.

Comment: @SakthiKarthik exactly but wat i need to write inside function??

Comment: just store an array. and use ajax auto complete.

Comment: I feel you chose a wrong UI component for your requirement, in such cases a Dropdown is more useful, it will let your user to easily pick up value and to some extent reduce your risk for violating validation check.

Comment: @GauravGupta my requirement is like this. I have to do based on this. Hope you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this $('#codeId').val().replace(/ /g,'').match(/^[A-Za-z]{1,}-[A-Za-z]{1,}((,[A-Za-z]{1,}-[A-Za-z]{1,})+)?$/); It will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

I can go for this expression:

```
/^[A-Za-z]*-[A-Za-z]*$/
```

`^` depicts the start of the string

`$` depicts the end of the string

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var valid = $('textarea').val().match(/^[A-Za-z]*-[A-Za-z]*$/);
        if(valid)
        {
            alert("Valid");
        }
        else 
            alert("Not valid");
    })
})
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/2hmwcamj/2/)

Comment: u mean i need to check if(val== ([A-Za-z]{1,100}-[A-Za-z]{1,100})){ validation}?? Right??

Comment: From his question example it seems that there is a space between '-'. Therefore, I'd slightly edit your answer with:  /([A-Za-z ]{1,100}-[ A-Za-z]{1,100})/. Still this is not really clear what he asks for.

Comment: @androidsuckzzz just go with the expression I said before it works ;-).   var valid = $('textarea').val().match(/^[A-Za-z]*-[A-Za-z]*$/);

Comment: @androidsuckzzz A bit hard to get exactly what is a valid string for you. I guess this should do it from what you just said: var valid = $('textarea').val().match(/^[A-Za-z]{1,}-[A-Za-z]{1,}((,[A-Za-z]{1,}-[A-Za-z]{1,})+)?$/);
http://jsfiddle.net/2hmwcamj/8/

Comment: @androidsuckzzz you need to be more specific about what you want. As I said in my answer: var valid =$('textarea').val().match(/^[^-,]{1,}-[^-,]{1,}((,[^-,]{1,}-[^-,]{1,})+)?$/); will work for any special character. if you want to keep the same syntax use  var valid = $('textarea').val().match(/^[ A-Za-z]{1,}-[ A-Za-z]{1,}((,[ A-Za-z]{1,}-[ A-Za-z]{1,})+)?$/); and please next time tick my answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Autocomplete**

```
// You can append strategies to an already existing textcomplete object.
$('#textarea1').textcomplete([
    { // tech companies
        words: ['apple', 'google', 'facebook', 'github'],
        match: /\b(\w{2,})$/,
        search: function (term, callback) {
            callback($.map(this.words, function (word) {
                return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
            }));
        },
        index: 1,
        replace: function (word) {
            return word + ' ';
        },
        placement: 'top'
    }
]);
```

Comment: I dont want autocomplete, I need onchange validation

Answer (score 0):

As commented before, if you wish to have a string like this: `string - string` without any special character with optionally `, string - string` you can use this regex:

```
var valid = $('textarea').val().match(/^[A-Za-z ]{1,}-[A-Za-z ]{1,}((,[A-Za-z ]{1,}-[ A-Za-z ]{1,‌​})+)?$/);
```

if you want to accept any special character for you string use:

```
var valid =$('textarea').val().match(/^[^-,]{1,}-[^-,]{1,}((,[^-,]{1,}-[^-,]{1,})+)?$/);
```